# C# - OpenXML Cell.InnerText is returning a decimal cell value as 8.8000000000000007

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

When i try to import a excel file using OpenXML sdk (C#), i am getting a weird cell value . The value is coming as **8.8000000000000007** but in the sheet the value is just **8.8**. I have checked the cell formatting but nothing seems wrong with that.

Comment: Looks like this is a calculated cell and `8.8` you see is a rounded value.

Comment: You should change that code line you see in the screen, to the code I am thinking about. Is it clear to you what I am talking about? No? This is how you explaining your issue - it's unclear what have coded. Please share some relevant code.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can round the cell value with [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2) to a specified number of fractional digits.

Comment: I can do that but i am not able to find the reason why the value is that long. when i open the excel and check the value it is just one decimal places